# Case statement saying it appeared before

Tags: c++, sdl

I have these 2 `case` statements:

```
case SDLK_w && SDLK_a:
{
    ball.posX -= mers;
    ball.posY -= mers;
    break;
}

case SDLK_w && SDLK_d:
{
    ball.posX += mers;
    ball.posY -= mers;
    break;
}
```

The second `SDLK_w` gives me an error saying:

> case label value has already appeared in this switch

It may be because `case` statements don't work with `&&`, but it only shows me an error at the second `W` key and not at the first one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `&&` returns either `true` or `false`. Probably `true`, since `SDLK_??` should be nonzero. So you have `case true:`, twice. It only complains about the second one, since it's repeated.

Comment: Also: you shouldn't use keycodes for game controls, those do the wrong thing on exotic layouts such as AZERTY. Use scancodes: `SDL_SCANCODE_W` and the respective field in the events, on AZERTY scancodes will rebind to differently named keys in the right locations.

Comment: Ok makes sense, and as for the other layouts that is a great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @yesyes, it appears you have a misconception that the cases of a switch statement can be expressions. In C++, cases can only be literal values. For your particular logic, you might consider using a chain of `if..elseif..elseif..else` statements.

Comment: @effect They can be expressions, as long as they are `constexpr` (otherwise OP would get a different error).

Comment: @effect i tried using `if...elseif...` but it simply doesnt work so i continued with cases

Comment: @yesyes You should try again, since that is what you need.

Comment: It would help if you show the `switch` statement, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDLK_w && SDLK_a` is another way of writing 1 because they are both true.
`SDLK_w && SDLK_d` is also another way of writing 1.

Perhaps you meant this

```
case SDLK_w:
case SDLK_a: // two case statements in a row: both of them run the same code
{
    ball.posX -= mers;
    ball.posY -= mers;
    break;
}

case SDLK_w:
case SDLK_d:
{
    ball.posX += mers;
    ball.posY -= mers;
    break;
}
```

but it still doesn't make sense because `SDLK_w` has two cases.

Comment: Well i already have a `case SDLK_w: {ball.posY -= mers;}`, so how should i handle that too?

Comment: @yesyes it seems that no one is correctly guessing what you believe `case SDLK_w && SDLK_a:` means.  It is only clear that it doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: If you look at the layout of those keys on the keyboard, very little of the code makes sense.  I'd focus on that aspect of things OP: decide what behaviour each of these keys should make happen and then program accordingly.

Comment: @yesyes what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @user253751 it should just move a ball up and down, left and right, diagonally, but i deleted the diagonally idea, and i kept the rest, so now it works

Comment: @yesyes What is the diagonally idea?

Comment: @user253751 that diagonally thing was when pressing W and A, the ball should move diagonally, but i scrapped it cuz i did it differently

Comment: @yesyes It looks like (because you didn't show it all) this part of code is handling **one** key press. If you press W and A at the same time, that's two keys. SDL would tell you that the player pressed W, and separately tell you that the player pressed A.